# http-server not starting in systemd

Tags: angularjs, node.js, linux, systemd

I'm using [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to server a simple Angular application. The application runs fine when I run it from bash. But when I try to run from systemd unit file, it fails.

This is the systemd unit file I've used to run it.

```
[Unit]
Description=web_app
Requires=network.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/http-server -p 80
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/deepcareweb_dev  
Restart=always
RestartSec=10                        
StandardOutput=syslog               
StandardError=syslog                
SyslogIdentifier=web_app
User=root
#Group=<alternate group>
#Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1337

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What should I do to run `http-server` from systemd unit file?

Edit 1 : `systemctl status`

```
$ sudo systemctl status web_app


● web_app.service - web_app
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/web_app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-03-05 06:17:14 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 1879 ExecStart=/usr/bin/http-server -p 80 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 1354 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: web_app.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=200
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: Failed to start web_app.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: web_app.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: web_app.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: web_app.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: Stopped web_app.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: web_app.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 05 06:17:14 ip-172-31-22-251 systemd[1]: Failed to start web_app.
```

Comment: How are you running it and what error are you getting?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid When I run `sudo systemctl start web_app` it says `Job for web_app.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status web_app.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Comment: ...and what's the log say? `systemctl status web_app` ?

Comment: I've added `systemctl status web_app` result in question

Comment: This question is a variation of the FAQ [Why does my script work in the bash CLI but not in systemd?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239)

Comment: Did you ever figure out why RestartSec=10 is being ignored? - I'm seeing the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "Restart=always" line, as it is triggering the "Start request repeated too quickly" error. After you remove it, you should have a real error message.

In my case the error "Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/local/bin/http-server: No such file or directory"

Changing the "WorkingDirectory" variable to "/" and the "ExecStart" to "/usr/bin/http-server WORKINGDIRECTORY -p 80" solved it for me.